# Welcome file list issue in Jetty, works fine with Jboss

Tags: jboss, jetty, web.xml

Issue I'm facing is as follows.
In Jboss I have web.xml as follows...

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.exp.ServletExample</servlet-class>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
               <welcome-file>NewFile.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

</servlet>
```

And when I try _http://localhost:8800/SimpleServletProject/ - [SimpleServletProject is the war file name] then my welcome file i.e. NewFile.html is getting displayed.

If I put the same war on jetty and type _http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/ it doesn't work... I get 404 error saying 
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /SimpleServletProject/index.jsp. Reason: not found

My war structure is as follows

```
SimpleServletProject.war
-META-INF
-WEB-INF
-NewFile.html
```

I'm struggling with this issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how are you deploying it into jetty?  placing war file into /webapps directory?  look at the logs, is it deploying your war file? logs will tell you what context it is deployed to, is it the same as you expect?

Comment: I'm placing it in /webapps folder, yes it is deploying, I can check that from the log.2013-06-12 16:57:35.846:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/SimpleServletProject,file:/C:/Users/sanjay_shivanna/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-SimpleServletProject.war-_SimpleServletProject-any-/webapp/},D:\jetty-distribution-7.6.8.v20121106\webapps\SimpleServletProject.war

Comment: Your example XML is invalid XML (you have an extra `</servlet>` close tag).  Also note, per the Servlet spec, "index.html", "index.htm", and "index.jsp" are defaulted as part of the `<welcome-file-list>`.  Do you have any jsps in your project?  (hard to tell, as your stated "war structure" is also incomplete and invalid)

Comment: thanks joakim for pointing it out, that was a copy paste mistake. and I don't have any jsp in my project. As I stated earlier, the same war file works fine with JBOSS with same web.xml file and Directory structure mentioned above(corrected the structure for more clarity). Facing issue when I try to deploy it on jetty... I even referred the jetty wiki where they mention about welcomefile list... but it was not very clear to me.